# Counting the sequence of a value in the tail of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the count of 1s at the **tail** of a pandas dataframe. From this dataframe:

```
x 
1
2
3
1
1
1
```

I want to get the count of **3**. If there are no 1s in the tail, then the function should return 0. I could not find any function of pandas to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's use this:

```
d1.x[::-1].eq(1).cumprod().sum()
```

Comment: this is clever !

Comment: That guy doesn't know what he's talking about... this is clever.

Comment: Okay. if you run it step by step, you'll see.  First thing I do is to reverse order the series, this  is because you said "last". Next, I check to see if that value is equal to 1, next I use cumprod to count the 1's at the end of the series, if the value doesn't equal to one it makes the cumprod go to zero.  Lastly, you sumup all the values where cumprod returned 1.

Comment: @renakre, do what I did, break it down one piece at a time, and just print out each step.  It is fairly straight forward.  Magic is that cumprod() will goto and then stay at zero, the first time it sees a false (ie: 0).

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks, you've done a great job in explaining better than I.