# How do I calculate the number of consecutive columns with zero values from the right until the first non zero element occurs

Tags: python, pandas, sum, reverse, cumsum

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4  
0  1  2  3  0  
1  4  0  0  0  
2  0  0  0  3  
3  0  3  0  0
```

Then I want to add another column such that it will display the number of zero valued column that occur contiguously from the right.
The new column would be:

```
  Cnew  
0 1  
1 3  
2 0  
3 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

- reverse order by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and `[::-1]`
- get [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) per row (`axis=1`)
- check [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and get [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of `True`s

---

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   C1  C2  C3  C4  new
0   1   2   3   0    1
1   4   0   0   0    3
2   0   0   0   3    0
3   0   3   0   0    2
```

```
print (df.iloc[:,::-1])
   C4  C3  C2  C1
0   0   3   2   1
1   0   0   0   4
2   3   0   0   0
3   0   0   3   0


print (df.iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1))
   C4  C3  C2  C1
0   0   3   5   6
1   0   0   0   4
2   3   3   3   3
3   0   0   3   3

print (df.iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1).eq(0))
      C4     C3     C2     C1
0   True  False  False  False
1   True   True   True  False
2  False  False  False  False
3   True   True  False  False
```

Comment: What is cumsum doing?

Comment: it is cumulative sum, - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html

Comment: there is `3,2,1` and it count `0+3, 0+3+2, 0+3+2+1`

Comment: in last row `0,0+0, 0+0+3, 0+0+3+0`

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `argmax` on a boolean array.  Also, if I skip straight to `numpy` I can make this very fast.

```
(df.values[:, ::-1] != 0).argmax(1)

array([1, 3, 0, 2])
```

Or very similarly

```
(df.values[:, ::-1].astype(bool)).argmax(1)

array([1, 3, 0, 2])
```

I can place it in a new column with `assign`

```
df.assign(new=(df.values[:, ::-1] != 0).argmax(1))

   C1  C2  C3  C4  new
0   1   2   3   0    1
1   4   0   0   0    3
2   0   0   0   3    0
3   0   3   0   0    2
```

Or add a new column in place

```
df['new'] = (df.values[:, ::-1] != 0).argmax(1)
df

   C1  C2  C3  C4  new
0   1   2   3   0    1
1   4   0   0   0    3
2   0   0   0   3    0
3   0   3   0   0    2
```

---

**Timing**
We reduce the time by reducing the work necessary.  We only need to find the position of the first non-zero.

```
# My first variant
%timeit df.assign(new=(df.values[:, ::-1] != 0).argmax(1))
# My second variant
%timeit df.assign(new=(df.values[:, ::-1].astype(bool)).argmax(1))
# jezrael's solution
%timeit df.assign(new=df.iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(1).eq(0).sum(1))
# numpy version of jezrael's solution
%timeit df.assign(new=(df.values[:,::-1].cumsum(1) == 0).sum(1))
# Scott Boston's solution
%timeit df.assign(new=df.iloc[:,::-1].eq(0).cumprod(axis=1).sum(axis=1))
# numpy version of Scott Boston's solution
%timeit df.assign(new=(df.values[:,::-1] == 0).cumprod(1).sum(1))
```

*small data*

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 301 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 273 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 770 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 323 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 647 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 324 µs per loop
```

*larger data*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], (10000, 100), p=(.7, .3)))

100 loops, best of 3: 6.03 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 5.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `eq`, `cumprod` and `sum` (This is very similiar to a question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986817/counting-the-sequence-of-a-value-in-the-tail-of-a-dataframe/43986918#43986918).)

```
df.iloc[:,::-1].eq(0).cumprod(axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    3
2    0
3    2
dtype: int64
```